# JS Operator precedent logical and comparison

Tags: javascript, operators

I know this has been asked a million times. But I can't find one that answers my questions directly. Just similar kinds of questions.

So this statement.

```
1 == !""
```

According to MDN operator precedent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Logical NOT has a higher precedent than equality.

It also mentions, assignment operators are right-associativity. Thus everything else must be left-associativity.

So on that statement. I'd of thought it would run as

```
!"" (coerce to a bool value, flip the value)
1 == true (compare the value)
```

But based on reading further down and the associativity mentions. It should run from left-to-right. Right? Which end up being the same thing, but it checks

```
1 == 
... then does the type coerce stuff
```

is my thinking right? Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: `1 == !""` -> `1 == true` -> `1 == 1` (ECMA 2015: [12.10.3 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) -> [7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison))

Comment: the operands of a comparator must be resolved values before the comparison can be performed.

Comment: associativity only matters when you have two operators with the same priority, as in `a < b > d` or `a + b - c`. In your example, `!` has a higher priority than `==` and thus evaluated first. Generally, when you're in doubt about how an expression is parsed, paste it into the [Esprima playground](https://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=1%20%3D%3D%20!%22%22) to see  what exactly is going on.